# Draw charts with a Loop using HighCharts in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, highcharts, symfony-3.1

I am currently using Highcharts in symfony. It works good when I enter static data (array1/array2/array3/array4) like this:

```
$ob1 = new Highchart();
$ob1->chart->renderTo('barchart');
$ob1->title->text('Chart 1');
$ob1->xAxis->categories($arrayResult);
$ob1->plotOptions->pie(array(
    'allowPointSelect'  => true,
    'cursor'    => 'pointer',
    'dataLabels'    => array('enabled' => false),
    'showInLegend'  => true
));

$ob1->series(array(array('type' => 'column','name' => 'bar1', 'data' => $array1),
                    (array('type' => 'column','name' => 'bar2', 'data' => $array2)),
                    (array('type' => 'column','name' => 'bar3', 'data' => $array3)),
                    (array('type' => 'column','name' => 'bar4', 'data' => $array4))


    ));
```

but what I need is to enter data within a loop because I have an irregular number of arrays. I tried this but I got an error "unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)"    Is there anything I have missed here?

Here is my code using while to add Chart's Data Series:

```
      $i=1;
      $number=4;

    $ob1->series(array( 
        (   
         $myarray = array();
         while($i <= $number): array_push($myarray, array(0 => 'value', 1=> $i));
          $i++;
          array('type' => 'column','name' => 'bar'.$i, 'data' => $myarray)
          endwhile;
        ),

));
```

I also tried this and displays only the last iteration of the while

```
     $i=1;
     $number=4;
     $myarray = array();

 while($i <= $number): 
     array_push($myarray, array(0 => 'value', 1=> $i));
     $i++;
     $ob1->series(array (array('type' => 'column','name' => 'bar'.$i, 'data' => $myarray)));
 endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php statement is not valid, has invalid syntax. To avoid this type of error, never create a loop inside the function argument. Simplify your syntax and use temporal variables, is easy to read and to understand what are you doing, remember, every good developer always say: "divide and conquer" :)

```
$i = 1;
$number = 4;

$chartData = [];
while ($i <= $number) {
    $chartData[] = [
        'type' => 'column',
        'name' => 'bar'.$i,
        'data' => [
            'value',
            $i,
        ],
    ];
    $i++;
}
$ob1->series($chartData);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @rafrsr :))

Comment: Can you help me with this please if you have any idea and thanks in advance :)) @rafrsr  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066259/symfony-offline-installation-with-composer