# Symfony offline installation with composer

Tags: php, symfony, server, composer-php, symfony-3.1

I'm trying to **install Symfony on a server**, which has **no connection to the internet**. I copied composer on the server but when i try to install it i get this error

*Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org*

Is there any possible way to install symfony without active connection to the internet; like download the framework, put it on the server and then run the composer offline? Or does it have too many dependencies, which would be included?

I've already googled but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

Comment: You said you copy the files... also copy the vendor directory.

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
composer install -o
```

to install. Then do all preparations like clear cache in prod/dev build assets and dump them

```
   php app/console cache:clear && php app/console cache:clear -e prod --no-debug
   php app/console assetic:dump -e prod --no-debug
   php app/console assets:install web --symlink --relative
```

then push/ftp your project to a server. I **highly recomend** you to run

```
composer dumpautoload -o
```

in order to **update autolaod files on the server**

#### UPDATE:

You could (should) also run a symfony's after-install script (after dumping autoload) in order to edit/update your `parameters.yml` on the Server, since db-access, mailer_transport will be probably different than on your dev-machine

```
composer run-script post-install-cmd
php app/console cache:clear -e prod --no-debug
```

then just run

```
php/console list
```

if you'll get a list of all available commands => your symfony app was **successfully installed** and runs

Comment: Actually I don't think you need to clear cache and dump assets in advance. You should be able to run those commands on the server even if it's offline.

Comment: I installed composer and copied all the files' project, but when i try to open the symfony project i get this error "the requested URL was not found on this server" Do you have any idea how to configure it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run composer on computer with connection to internet and copy all directory with files.

Composer to work mast make connection to internet, to check new version of package.

Comment: Do you mean i should run composer on my machine and then copy symfony project to the server without need to install composer on the server?

Comment: I installed composer and copied all the files' project, but when i try to open the symfony project i get this error "the requested URL was not found on this server" Do you have any idea how to configure it ?

Comment: Thank you @janek1 but this solution doen't work for me. Do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **yes** and there are several ways to do that

As others have suggested the best choice is to build your project (install Symfony, install Composer, update dependencies) on a system that **is** connected to the internet and then just copy the project on the server.

## Warning

The system where you build the project should be as similar as possible to the actual server (I mean PHP version, MySQL version, and so on) else the project may breaks.

You may want to build a Virtual Machine to make it really similar, which is good for development also. In that case you may take a look at tools like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem in symfony3.

**Solution:**

1. Create archive of project - for safety.
2. Copy project form `server` to computer with internet access (all files & directory): `laptop`.
3. Run `composer update` on laptop.
4. On server:

   rm -rf app/*
   rm -rf bin/*
   rm -rf var/cache/*
   rm -rf var/logs/*
   rm -rf var/sessions/*
   rm -rf vendor/*
   rm composer.json
   rm composer.lock
5. Copy from laptop to server files to directory: `app/`, `bin/`, `vendor/` and `composer.json`, `composer.lock`

Its work for me :-)

Comment: Thanks @Grene for your solution but it doesn't work for me. I've updated composer and then copied the project from laptop to server but still not working. Do you have any other solution?